# REMOTE_ADDR show wrong IP on nginx

Tags: php, nginx, ip, global-variables

we have a dedicated server which installed nginx.

when I use $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] this variable return Server IP, because we have Nginx.

I know we should use HTTP_X_REAL_IP or HTTP_X_FORWARDED but we have some PHP application which use REMOTE_ADDR and the source of this applications are coded with IonCube so we cannot change on source of this programs.

Is there any way in nginx configuration to return correct user IP in REMOTE_ADDR not in another indexes ?

Comment: Se the module http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRealipModule

Comment: with this module I should use HTTP_X_REAL_IP and I cannot use REMOTE_ADDR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx allows you set new environment variables with the [env directive](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxCoreModule#try_files). You can read [arbitrary headers as variables](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24http_HEADER) using using `$http_HEADER`.

I have not tried this combination of features, but rewriting the `REMOTE_ADDR` variable in Nginx appears to be what you are looking to do, this appears to be a way to do it.

Comment: is there a way to setheader host TO server address chosen. So if server www.a.com is chosen then set host header to www.a.com and then send request to that server

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_client_ip()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) { // check ip from share internet
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) { // to check ip is pass from proxy
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

try this?

Comment: Thank you, but I said I cannot change the source code, the source is encoded with IonCube

Answer (score 0):

If there are no stock solutions, patching Nginx to behave as you require would be an approach you could take. An alternative would be to patch PHP so that the desired value is available in $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].